# Python - Parsing repeated patterns from a large string

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a large string into a group of items given a certain pattern.  The pattern always begins with the same two words and ends in a number.

Example:

```
stringSnippet = "**1111 Text** i want everything here onward.affe .afefa .afeaf .afeaf .afaef words .affe .afefa .afeaf .afeaf .afaef up until here **6**"
```

How would I use regex to take all values between `1111 Text` and the number `6`?
And repeat this process to group the same patterns from the entire string?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your request correctly, the regex is:

```
r'1111 Text(.*?)6'
```

This translates to, "find the shortest block of text starting with '1111 Text` and ending with '6', keep all the text between to delimiters.

You can use that in an *re.findall()*.  As the name implies, it will find all instances of that pattern in the string.

You might or might not want to add an `re.DOTALL` to allow newlines to be captured between the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('1111 Text(.*?)6', stringSnippet)
```

The above expression will match the pattern above in stringSnippet, and will return all the found occurrences as a list.